# Invalid JAVA_HOME path with Cordova

Tags: java, cordova

When I do `cordova run android` (either on cmder or windows 10 command prompt), it's not working because of a problem with java.
Here's the error :

`Android Studio project detected
(node:10916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161`

The `java` works well, the `javac` is not working.

Here's the JAVA_HOME system variable :
[JAVA_HOME system variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQecl.png)

Here's the PATH system variable : [PATH system variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR9WQ.png)

I tried several things but it's still not working. I restarted both my computer and my command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a JDK (Java Development Kit). You currently have a JRE (Java runtime environment)

To do this, download a jdk, and set the JAVA_HOME variable to the jdk. Then you should be able to run javac (the java compiler) in your command line.

The JDK contains a JRE. Hence everything you were able to do until this point, you will still be able to do.

Also you can set a JRE_HOME and an JDK_HOME. Your Variables could look like this then:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xxx
JRE_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%\jre
JDK_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
```

And also don't forget to add it to the Path:

```
Path: other entries; %JAVA_HOME%\bin; other entries
```

Comment: Thanks! After installing the JDK from the link given in the error I faced a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater` error, so I had to uninstall java and install the [JDK 1.8 downloaded from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java is the java runner, while javac is the compiler. If you are making an android app, you need to compile it.

can you ensure you have the JDK installed? `javac -v`

if not, you need to install it and find the binary and add it to your system variables.

[system variables for JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWDuT.png)